# Information gain for decision tree in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, decision-tree, information-gain

I am using **GainRatioAttributeEval** in Weka. I got this result

[image]

I can not interpret this result. I mean what does this portion mean?

```
Ranked attributes:
 1.0000000000000009    5 Na_to_K
 0.3935404073616423    3 BP
 0.2063964793752467    1 Age
 0.09316668988826002   4 Cholesterol
 0.007712386387024157  2 Sex
```

My dataset has 6 attributes with 200 instances. Among them drug is my class attribute. I am also attaching the preprocess overview of the dataset.

[image]

I know how to calculate information gain and create a decision tree. But I can not get this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gain ratio](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/attributeSelection/GainRatioAttributeEval.html) and [info gain](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/attributeSelection/InfoGainAttributeEval.html) are two separate attribue evaluation methods with different formulas. See the linked Javadoc for more information.

Comment: The information is very helpful. Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69698962/infogainattributeeval-working-principal-in-weka