# InfoGainAttributeEval working principal in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, classification, binary-tree, weka, decision-tree

I am using InfoGainAttributeEval in Weka. I got this result

[image]

The result is not clear to me still I try to create a tree based upon my theoretical understanding.

[image]

I would like to know am I correct to making the tree? Because in the tree all right children are empty.

The dataset look like

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you're trying.to create a tree? All the InfoGain attribute evaluator (or any attribute evaluator) does, is compute a score/merit per attribute, which is used for ranking the attributes by importance. That way, you can pick, eg, the three most important ones or all attributes above a certain threshold.

Comment: What does it mean Selected attribute: 5 3 1 4 2? The decision tree I drew is it ok?

Comment: The Ranker, as the name suggests, outputs the attributes in the order of their importance that the chosen attribute evaluation algorithm generated. No decision tree involved.